# Action method not showing in Web API, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API, I  have written action method. but it's not correctly visible when I run the application. I cannot see SendPushNotification in the attached image.

[image]

Controller Code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/OTP")]
public class OTPController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return Ok("value");
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult SendPushNotification(string userId, string factorId, string domain)
    {
        var response = _oTPRepository.SendPushNotification(userId, factorId, domain);

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

Comment: How are your routes configured?  Are you using `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`?

Comment: you won't see methods, you will only see resources.

Comment: @Amy I am  using everything default

Comment: your action is the 2nd `GET` listed.

Comment: @DanielA.White but how would I recognize if I have multiple methods with same parameters

Comment: make the method make sense (like a POST) and provide a description. you can't have multiple actions with conflicting parameters. the router won't be able to figure out what to call.

Comment: But in other Web API application, the method name is visible, so I am wondering why its not visible in this application

Comment: You're using convention based routing?  Can you be more specific than "everything default"?  You are using mapping attributes but didn't use `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`?

Comment: @viveknuna is it just help page issue?

Comment: Do `[HttpGet, ActionName("SendPushNotification")]`. If you have other actions where it works out-of-the-box, then show your route mapping. That aside: semantically it doesn't make sense to have an action where data is send to, to listen on the verb GET. It should be a POST action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a Route over your method, something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("SendPushNotification")]
    public IHttpActionResult SendPushNotification(string userId, string factorId, string domain)
    {
        var response = _oTPRepository.SendPushNotification(userId, factorId, domain);

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

This will combine with the RoutePrefix from your controller and give you what you want.
You can call it whatever you want as well, whatever makes sense for your API.

Answer (score 0):

in mentioned image second method is that for which you are actually looking for.
default routing for action methods is api/{controller_name}.
if you want to access that method as your given name you have set routing attribute above that action method.
like [Routing("api/OTP/SendPushNotification")]